# Sum distinct group values only

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to sum values distinct per group. Pardon the wordy post...

Context. Suppose I have a table of the form:

```
ID  Foo Value
A   1   2
B   0   2
C   0   3
A   1   2
A   1   2
C   0   3
B   0   2
```

Each ID/Foo combo has a distinct value. I'd like to join this table onto another cte that has a cumulative field, e.g. suppose after joining using `rows unbounded preceeding` I have a new field called cumulative. Same data, just duplicated 3 times with value cumulative:

```
ID  Foo Value   Cumulative
A   1   2   1
B   0   2   1
C   0   3   1
A   1   2   1
A   1   2   1
C   0   3   1
B   0   2   1
A   1   2   2
B   0   2   2
C   0   3   2
A   1   2   2
A   1   2   2
C   0   3   2
B   0   2   2
A   1   2   3
B   0   2   3
C   0   3   3
A   1   2   3
A   1   2   3
C   0   3   3
B   0   2   3
```

I want to add a new field 'segment_value' that, for each foo gets the sum of distinct ID values. E.g. The distinct ID/Foo combinations are:

```
ID  Foo Value
A   1   2
B   0   2
C   0   3
```

I would therefore like a new field, 'segment_value', That returns 2 for `Foo=1` and 5 for `Foo=0`. Desired result:

```
ID  Foo Value   Cumulative  segment_value
A   1   2   1   2
B   0   2   1   5
C   0   3   1   5
A   1   2   1   2
A   1   2   1   2
C   0   3   1   5
B   0   2   1   5
A   1   2   2   2
B   0   2   2   5
C   0   3   2   5
A   1   2   2   2
A   1   2   2   2
C   0   3   2   5
B   0   2   2   5
A   1   2   3   2
B   0   2   3   5
C   0   3   3   5
A   1   2   3   2
A   1   2   3   2
C   0   3   3   5
B   0   2   3   5
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you explained your problem very well and I might have misunderstood something, but can't you extract the `segment_value` using a query such as this one:

```
select 
    foo, 
    sum(val) as segment_value
from (
    select distinct foo, val from table
) tab
group by foo
```

this would return the following result:

```
foo segment_value
1   2
0   5
```

then you could join this to the rest of you query and use it as per your needs.